# How to update (ajax) partial form after loading for nested fields in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

On railscasts.com episode #74 presents a way to dynamically adding a partial form for nested fields to existing form. Here is the helper method playing the magic:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
      new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
      fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
        render :partial => association.to_s, :locals => {:f => builder, :i_id => 0} 
      end
      link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{j fields}\")")
end
```

Here is an example of adding partial form in a view:

```
<p><%= link_to_add_fields t("Add Product"), f, :order_items %></p>
```

Here is an example of the partial form `order_items` used in our rails app:

```
  <%= f.input :quote_id, :label => t("Quote#"), :collection => @quotes,  :include_blank => true  %>
  .......
```

The `order_items` has a `@quotes`. When a user selects a supplier, then we would like only present the quotes which only belong to the supplier (@quotes = @quotes.where(:supplier_id => the_supplier_id). The problem is that the @quotes on partial `order_items` can not be updated (or we don't know how) after being loaded first time. Is it possible to update `@quotes` on the partial `order_items` with ajax call after loading?